# Problem about analytical continuation

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D$ be a connected open set in $\mathbb C$, let $a\in D$, and let $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ be holomorphic on $D$. Given that the series of n-th differentiation of $f$ at the point $a$ converges, namely 
$$|f(a) + f'(a) + f''(a) + f'''(a) + ... | < ∞,$$ show that:

1. $f$ is holomorphic on the entirety of $\mathbb C$;
2. the series $$S(z) = f(z) + f'(z) + f''(z) + f'''(z) + ... $$ is inner-closed uniformly convergent on $C$, i.e. for every compact set $K$ in $\mathbb C$, the series converges uniformly on $K$.

---

I thought it would be enough to prove that $f$ can be expanded to a Taylor series everywhere in $\mathbb C$. So I used 
$$f(z) = f(a) + \int_{[a,z]} f'(w)dw$$
 for every point $z$. 
 Then, $$|f(z) + f'(z) +...| \leq |f(a) + f'(a) +…|\cdot(1 + |z-a|),$$
  for every $z$. 
But then I was stuck because $|z-a| \to ∞$ as $|z|\to ∞$. So the Taylor series of the point $z$ may not converge?
Sorry if my idea is totally wrong because I am just beginner to complex analysis and all I know come from textbooks...
Please post me a right way to solve the problem, thank you!

Comment: Please tell us what have you have tried, or precisely what you are stuck on.

Comment: Sorry I am new to here. I will edit it

Comment: Claim #1 is obviously false as you place no constraints on how $f$ must behave on $\Bbb{C}/D$. You could perhaps show that the restriction of $f$ to D extends to a holomorphic function on all of $\Bbb{C}$.

Comment: Also, I believe your hypothesis should be that $\sum |f^{(n)}(a)|$ converges, but I may be wrong.

Comment: So? I have got an answer to it by proving that the convergence radius is infinity.